# What's the difference between down voting and flagging?

Tags: discussion, flags

They both ultimately mean the same thing, right? As a new user I can't down vote but can flag. Am I right in assuming down voting costs me points whereas flagging doesn't?

So if I wanted to report a suitably bad question, flagging is the way to go, but as a very high rep user with 2 years worth of rep exceeding thousands where rep score means very little, if I wanted to p%ss off a newbie, I'd down vote?

I've flagged quite a few (of what I believed to be) poor questions to no gain, but don't understand what a down vote really represents to most users because from what I can deduce, people downvote then flag anyway?

Comment: i could down vote this very question for lack of research effort, but i would not flag it.

Comment: _"if I wanted to p%ss off a newbie, I'd down vote"_ - You got it wrong. Downvotes are **not** for the current user. Votes are a signal for the _future_ users to indicate the quality of the post.

Answer (score 7):

Upvotes and downvotes are the way you express your opinion about the quality, clarity and usefulness of a post.

A flag is a communication to a moderator to report some adverse situation that cannot be normally handled by the user community.  Use flags when something bad is happening that you can't handle yourself.

As you can see, they are two completely different things.

**Further Reading**
[When should I vote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote)
[Why is voting important?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)
[What if I see someone doing something bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/flagging)
[What are acceptable reasons for flagging?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10848)

Comment: There are flags for low quality posts, flags for very badly worded questions and flags for useless posts. Everything a down vote represents!

Comment: No.  The only action a moderator can take in response to a flag is closure or deletion, and sometimes suspension.  Those actions have nothing to do with upvotes or  downvotes.

Comment: @user3791372 I could downvote your post for lack of research effort, technical inaccuracy, or anything I'd like, really. The same could not be said for flags: they require explicit community intervention.

Comment: Maybe you should only be able to down vote for specific reasons which you should / have to specify at the time of down voting otherwise the poster doesn't know if you down voted because you had a bad day or because x/y/z

Comment: [Been](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/102937) [there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222537), [done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31302) [that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205801).